Bottom row of keys will not type, unless they are held down for a random(?) amount of seconds, to which they then work for a bit before regressing
System
$ uname -r
6.6.23-1-rt28-MANJARO

$ cat /etc/*release 
Manjaro Linux
DISTRIB_ID="ManjaroLinux"
DISTRIB_RELEASE="24.0.0"
DISTRIB_CODENAME="Wynsdey"
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Manjaro Linux"
Manjaro Linux
NAME="Manjaro Linux"
PRETTY_NAME="Manjaro Linux"
ID=manjaro
ID_LIKE=arch
BUILD_ID=rolling
ANSI_COLOR="32;1;24;144;200"
HOME_URL="https://manjaro.org/"
DOCUMENTATION_URL="https://wiki.manjaro.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://forum.manjaro.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://docs.manjaro.org/reporting-bugs/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://manjaro.org/privacy-policy/"
LOGO=manjarolinux

$ plasmashell --version
plasmashell 6.0.4

Laptop Model: Thinkpad x390 Yoga

What is the basic problem?

For the past month, randomly, my bottom row of keys + the Enter key will stop functioning. They start working after I hold them down for about 15 seconds, or press the keys a large number of times.
Persistently for years, the fn key has always exhibitted this behaviour, even as I am writing this. ( Something I am just realizing now writing this post )

For example, just now when I press fn + F6, I had to press it 22 times to have it register 20 times. I then did fn + F5 and had to press it 87 times for it to register 20 times. When it did not register, it would simply pass F5 refreshing the page. It seems extremely random as to when it does this. More often, it doesnt work properly.
Have you experienced this over multiple kernels?
Yes.
Have you experienced this over multiple boots?
Yes.
Have you experienced this over multiple installs?
fn key, yes. Bottom row, no.
Do you have a special keyboard layout?
Yes. A custom one in fact, however it had never given me these issues prior and for many years.
Would this happen on a regular qwerty?
I have verified that fn behaviour happens on qwerty. I have not had the opportunity to test qwerty with the bottom row when the behaviour pops up.
How long does this happen for?
For the bottom row, sometimes it feels like it goes on for upwards of 30 minutes. Hard to say. It has not happened since I started writing this post. For the fn key, its persistent.
Does this happen on all programs?
Yes. If I am using Qutebrowser, and it starts to happen, if I open up Vim, it will continue to exhibit that behaviour.
Do you have any reason to believe it is hardware related?
Partially. My laptop fan has bad bearings ( Very Noisy and ineffecient, which is causing the CPU to throttle down ), and some strange behaviour has been experienced when things heat up, like my trackpoint just having odd resetting behaviour.
However, while I initially thought that perhaps there was some water damage on the keys, I have dismissed this because it is not about how hard I push on the keypads, but how long I hold them down.
That leaves me to believe that the hardware is functioning, but something is stopping them from registering until the key is pushed a certain amount of times.
Does it happen only when your laptop heats up?
I don't think so, because sometimes it happens fresh from boot, but I have not been able to detect a pattern of behaviour as to when it happens. It certainly has happened when I play a browser based game that has a fair bit of cpu usage though.
Are there any other odd behaviours?
After my bottom row starts functioning again, sometimes it double presses. Its hard to know for sure though.
What is your question?
Apart from the obvious, What is going on? or How can I fix this?, my question is how ought I go about debugging this?
Thanks.

Did you replace the normal laptop keyboard with the one you linked, or is it an extra peripheral? If it's extra and you unplug it, to use the laptop's keyboard does it happen with more than the function keys?

@eyoung100 Nope. Its just a remapping of the keys, that can be configured in /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/. What I do, is replace /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us with this file: https://qtchan.neocities.org/Downloads/us

Are the keys quiet, or do they click when you type?  See Type 3 under types of Keyboards.  As a test, disable your custom mapping, which i see no problem with.  If the bottom row of keys stick, even with the mapping disabled, then the bottom of the membrane is either worn or damaged by a spill etc.   Watch this video to run a diagnostic test.

@eyoung100 Are the keys quiet, or do they click when you type? As audibly quiet as any other chicklet keyboard. I've disabled the mapping and it does not work. I have not done the diagnostic, but it would be hard to anyways given that the keys only stop working for some of the time.
